# Can't manage the workstations in my AD homelab (COM+, WMI)

Tags: domain, wmi, com+

I'm having troubles managing the workstations on my AD homelab (Windows Server 2019).  It's not a network path issue because once the firewall on the remote host is disabled I can do Management.

The message:

"Computer workstation-1.ad.lab.home cannot be managed.... To enable the appropriate Windows Firewall rules on the remote computer, open Windows Firewalls with Advanced Security snap-in, and enable the following inbound Rules:

COM+ Network Access (DCOM-in)

All rules in in Remote Event Log Management group"

The policies I've made are:

**Policies\Administrative Templates\Network\Network Connections\Windows Firewall\Domain Profile**

Windows Defender Firewall: Allow inbound remote administration exception
Windows Defender Firewall: Allow inbound Remote Desktop exceptions

**Policies\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Windows Defender Firewall with Advanced Security\Windows Defender Firewall with Advanced Security\Inbound**

COM+ Network Access (DCOM-In)   COM+ Network Access All Yes

COM+ Remote Administration (DCOM-In)    COM+ Remote Administration  All Yes

File and Printer Sharing (Echo Request - ICMPv4-In) File and Printer Sharing    All Yes

Remote Access Management (DCOM-In)  Remote Access   All Yes

Remote Access Management (NP-In)    Remote Access   All Yes

Remote Access Management (NPS-RPC-In)   Remote Access   All Yes

Remote Access Management (RRAS-RPC-In)  Remote Access   All Yes

Remote Access Management (Services-RPC-In)  Remote Access   All Yes

Remote Access Management (WMI-In)   Remote Access   All Yes

Remote Desktop - Shadow (TCP-In)    Remote Desktop  All Yes

Remote Desktop - User Mode (TCP-In) Remote Desktop  All Yes

Remote Desktop - User Mode (UDP-In) Remote Desktop  All Yes

Remote Event Log Management (NP-In) Remote Event Log Management All Yes

Remote Event Log Management (RPC)   Remote Event Log Management All Yes

Remote Event Log Management (RPC-EPMAP) Remote Event Log Management All Yes

Remote Event Monitor (RPC)  Remote Event Monitor    All Yes

Remote Event Monitor (RPC-EPMAP)    Remote Event Monitor    All Yes

Remote Scheduled Tasks Management (RPC) Remote Scheduled Tasks Management   All Yes

Windows Management Instrumentation (ASync-In)   Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI)    All Yes

Windows Management Instrumentation (DCOM-In)    Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI)    All Yes

Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI-In) Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI)    All Yes

Windows Remote Management (HTTP-In) Windows Remote Management   Domain, Private Yes

Windows Remote Management (HTTP-In) Windows Remote Management   Public  Yes

Comment: welcome, home and enduser question are offtopic on serverfault.com but might be on topic on superuser.com instead

Comment: It is helpful to if you mention reproducible steps you do and mention results of these steps.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I solved this by deleting the policy and creating it again with just

Windows Defender Firewall: Allow inbound remote administration exception

Windows Defender Firewall: Allow inbound Remote Desktop exceptions

Perhaps something was corrupted in the first one. And while this is a homelab, the aim is to learn skills I can transfer in a real environment.